# Are the conditions ${c=ae+(b-e), d=e(b-e)}$ and $ad=(b-e)[c-(b-e)]$ equivalent?

Tags: polynomials

Respected All.

Please help me on the following.

Suppose that $x^5+ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e\in \mathbb R[x]$ can be written as 
$$(x^3+a_1x^2+b_1x+1)(x^2+b_2)$$ then we must have 
\begin{align*}
&a=a_1,\\
&b=b_1+b_2,\\
&c=a_1b_2+b_1,\\
&d=b_1b_2,\\
&e=b_2
\end{align*}
which reduces to 
\begin{align*}
&c=ae+(b-e),\\
&d=e(b-e)
\end{align*}
which are the required condition in order to get the above factorisation.

My question is the following:
What if we write the combine condition ? Because note that when the first condition is multiplied by $(b-e)$ we shall get $c(b-e)=ad+(b-e)^2$ and in other words $$ad=(b-e)[c-(b-e)]$$
will this condition be equivalent to the above two ? If not, kindly provide me some counter example. Also please show me how to search such counter example.

Thanking you in advance for your help

Comment: No. Try a = 2, b = c = e = 1, d = 0.

Comment: But $x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+1$ cannot be written in above form.

Comment: And so what? Please reread your own title.

Comment: Yup, @Did, one may multiply by $(b-e)$ without loss of equivalence iff $(b-e)\neq 0$.

Comment: I am little confused here.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin "iff $(b-e)\ne0$" ?? I doubt that. Try $a=b=d=2$, $c=5$, $e=1$.